# Django: manage.py loaddata is returning 'Deserialization Error'

Tags: python, json, django

So when I try to load data into my models from my .json file from cmd, it is giving me this error: 
[image]

It seems to be a problem with the 'category_id' but I'm not sure how I go about fixing this issue.

Here is my code:

shop/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()  
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product')

    def get_products(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(category=self)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_list_by_category',args=[self.id])


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

shop/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import Category, Product
from django.db.models import Count
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, InvalidPage

def product_list(request, category_id=None):
    category = None
    products = Product.objects.all()
    ccat = Category.objects.annotate(num_products=Count('products'))
    if category_id:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, id=category_id)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    paginator = Paginator(products, 3)
    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page', 1))
    except:
        page = 1
    try:
        products = paginator.page(page)
    except(EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'products.html',
                    {'products': products,
                    'countcat':ccat})
```

And this are the two .json files I wish to load into my database (worth noting that createcategories.json worked without issue)

createcategories.json

```
[
    {
        "model": "shop.category",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "name": "Europe"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "shop.category",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields": {
            "name": "North America"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "shop.category",
        "pk": 3,
        "fields": {
            "name": "South America"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "shop.category",
        "pk": 4,
        "fields": {
            "name": "Asia"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "shop.category",
        "pk": 5,
        "fields": {
            "name": "Africa"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "shop.category",
        "pk": 6,
        "fields": {
            "name": "Middle East"
        }
    }
]

I thought that the category_id would get added automatically as a foreign key bu it has not.

Many thanks in advance!
```

createproducts.json

```
[
    {
      "model": "shop.product",
      "pk": 1,
      "fields": {
        "category_id":1,
        "name": "Europe Title 1",
        "description": "Europe Description 1",
        "stock": 3,
        "price": 100.00
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "shop.product",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields": {
          "category_id":2,
          "name": "North America Title 1",
          "description": "North America Description 1",
          "stock": 4,
          "price": 7.00
          }
      },
      {
        "model": "shop.product",
        "pk": 3,
        "fields": {
          "category_id":3,
          "name": "South America Title 1",
          "description": "South America Desc 1",
          "stock": 100,
          "price": 2.00
          }
      },
      {
        "model": "shop.product",
        "pk": 4,
        "fields": {
          "category_id":4,
          "name": "Asia Title 1",
          "description": "Asia Desc 1",
          "stock": 50,
          "price": 1.00
          }
      },
      {
        "model": "shop.product",
        "pk": 5,
        "fields": {
          "category_id":5,
          "name": "Africa Title 1",
          "description": "Africa Desc 1",
          "stock": 9,
          "price": 99.00
          }
      },
      {
        "model": "shop.product",
        "pk": 6,
        "fields": {
          "category_id":4,
          "name": "Asia Title 2",
          "description": "Asia Desc 2",
          "stock": 1,
          "price": 50.00
          }
      },
      {
        "model": "shop.product",
        "pk": 7,
        "fields": {
          "category_id":1,
          "name": "Europe Title 2",
          "description": "Europe Desc 2",
          "stock": 2,
          "price": 300.00
          }
      },
      {
        "model": "shop.product",
        "pk": 8,
        "fields": {
          "category_id":4,
          "name": "Asia Title 3",
          "description": "Asia Desc 3",
          "stock": 2,
          "price": 75.00
          }
      },
      {
        "model": "shop.product",
        "pk": 9,
        "fields": {
          "category_id":6,
          "name": "Middle East Title 1",
          "description": "Middle East Desc 1",
          "stock": 1,
          "price": 50.00
          }
      },
      {
        "model": "shop.product",
        "pk": 10,
        "fields": {
          "category_id":6,
          "name": "Middle East Title 2",
          "description": "Middle East Desc 1",
          "stock": 2,
          "price": 15.00
          }
      }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `category_id` in `createproducts.json`, you should have `products` in `createcategories.json`.

My guess is that when the dump was created, there was a `ForeignKey` relation from `Product` to `Category`, but now there is a `ManyToMany` relation from `Category` to `Product`.

If you can live without the category assignment, you can just delete the `category_id` entries. Otherwise you have to rewrite both files.